# You must setup php-http/httplug-bundle to use the default http client service

Tags: php, symfony

I don't understand the following problem:

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
>   You must setup php-http/httplug-bundle to use the default http client
>   service.
>
> Script
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>   handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception [RuntimeException] 
>   An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'"                                                                               > command:
>   [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurati
>   onException]
>   You must setup php-http/httplug-bundle to use the default http client service.

Below is my file composer.json

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.3.4",
    "knplabs/knp-disqus-bundle": "dev-master",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "dev-master",
    "kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating": "dev-master",
    "azine/socialbar-bundle": "dev-master",
    "gregwar/captcha-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "~2.4",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "1.1.1",
    "php-http/httplug-bundle": "1.7.1"
},
    "require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle":" ~2.0@dev"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error comes from HWI Oauth Bundle: https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/HWIOAuthExtension.php

And judging by that code, your HTTPlug Bundle is not activated in your kernel, while HWI Oauth Bundle needs it to be activated for HWI bundle to work.

Follow the [instructions](https://github.com/php-http/HttplugBundle#install) and add the bundle to your kernel:

```
new Http\HttplugBundle\HttplugBundle(),
```

Comment: super I add the following line in my appkernel file. php and it works very well.

Answer (score 4):

Many thancks, Just i've add following line

```
    class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
        ...
        new Http\HttplugBundle\HttplugBundle(),
    );
```